# Как склонять умножение выше двадцати-сорока(?)?

Tags: согласование, орфоэпия, числительные

Помогите совы, коты, метромэтры, люди, человеки, все кто может!

Как склонять и ставить ударение при умножении чисел выше двадцати?

дважды два, трижды три, пя́тью пять, де́сятью десять, два́дцатью двадцать, тридцатью тридцать

сорокью сорок? или как?

а двадцать один? а пятьюдесятью?

а стами сто? или стожды? или сотью?

А умножение одного - однажды? о́днажды сто? (этот пункт закрыт, оди́ножды один)

+миллионажды.

Comment: Никак!  Не надо склонять то, что не склоняется.

Comment: хочу склонить несклоняемое и спрячь неспрягаемое, помогите.

Comment: С 21 не получится, потому что с 1 нет.

Comment: Да, *стожды*...

Comment: Да, одного тоже нет, вот дела...

Comment: Может "однажды"?

Comment: Нет, "однажды пять" не скажешь. *Однижды*, *одиножды*...

Comment: Да, точняк, одиножды!

Comment: А в словарь посмотреть? Одиножды, дважды, трижды и четырежды. Всё!

Comment: Хм, даже в словаре есть, тогда: *двадцати одиножды пять*)))

Comment: Дело в том, что это наречия, а не числительные. А наречия не образовываются. Но ненормальные можно образовать: *двестижды, тысячижды*.

Comment: Угу, наречия, почему наречия не образовываются?

Comment: Все в словарях... Новые не делаются... То, что наречие, подразумевает, что для каждого числа не будет наречия... Образовались для самых используемых чисел, для мелких... Ещё интересно, что после 4 меняется окончание (*4 банана, 5 бананов*) и уже нет нормального наречия. Может, не просто совпадение.

Comment: Это я знаю, считали раньше четверками или типа того, вообще считали в двенадцатеричной системе, десятеричная появилась позже. Считали по фалангам 4 пальцев с помощью большого, получалось три раза по 4, наверное поэтому только до 4, а пять - это весь кулак уже, то есть что-то целое-цельное. То есть пятаками тоже можно считать, но уже полные группы.

Comment: А по словообразованию было бы "п**я**тижды", "ш**е**стижды" и т.д.

Comment: Кстати, тогда "с**о**тежды". Лучше, чем "стожды")

Comment: миллионажды бывает), по крайней мере в интернете повторяется)

Comment: Расширение темы: https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=10257.0